# Is there a means to pass some php.ini settings to the drush command?

Tags: drush

Running `drush -d status` results in this error: `Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error`. The full output is add below.

> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.12 sec, 7.41
>   MB]
>   [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.12
>   sec, 7.41 MB]
>   [notice] Cache HIT cid:
>   5.7-commandfiles-2-c32acd775c18a90c5b41d0fc9accf5ab [0.13 sec, 7.41 MB]
>   [debug] Drush bootstrap phase :
>   _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.13 sec, 7.41 MB]                                                                       [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database()
>   [0.16 sec, 9.16 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.16 sec,
>   9.16 MB]                                                                                        [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full()
>   [0.17 sec, 9.16 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Undefined index: sitename domain.module:2922 [1.24 sec,
>   31.05 MB]                                                                                            [notice] Undefined index: path domain.module:2923 [1.24 sec, 31.05 MB]
>   [notice] Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable
>   error. [1.24 sec, 31.06 MB]
>   [error]

Is there a way to configure a separate `php.ini` for `drush` in the `.drushrc` file or in `settings.php`, or pass some settings on the `drush` invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that php.ini for Command Line Interface is separate and has nothing to do with php.ini your webserver is using. To find where that file is, follow [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057110/2389310) as this is not really on-topic on Drupal Answers.

If you want to set some php.ini values in drushrc.php, you need to use [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/ini_set) PHP function. Just remember that not all values are changeable like that, only the ones with `PHP_INI_USER` (or `PHP_INI_ALL`, of course) on [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Comment: Could you reverse the order of the paragraphs? I think most heavy drush users get to find that out sooner or later. I can do it myself if you don't mind. It sort of makes the answer scarier

I will ask the additional question at the bottom as a separate question.

Comment: @vfclists I really think that forgetting that there are separate php.ini for all interfaces is mistake made more often. And both paragraphs are so short that I don't think reading them would hurt anyone. If you will suggest edit, I'll not accept or reject it, I'll let other reviewers to decide which way is better.

Comment: I think it is better give the direct answer to the question first and add the `nota bene` afterwards. Without the additional note they will still get their desired result. It makes the process sound more scary than it is and Drupal users comfortable on the command line are likely to need less hand holding when the unexpected arises. They are probably used to such gotchas already.

Anyway we all have different opinions on styles of teaching.

Thanks for the answer.